# Can I connect 3 displays to a late 2012 Mac Mini?

Tags: display, mac-mini

I have the late 2012 Mac Mini, which has a HDMI port and a Thunderbolt port.

I have 3 1080p monitors that each have DVI, HDMI and VGA. Is it possible to connect them to my Mini, no mirroring?

Comment: did you look up your system specs?

Comment: @Buscar웃 yes, it's the late 2012 i7 Mini.